# RXJS on first emit

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'd like to `map` the value, but only the first time it's emitting. The other times it can pass through. Any ideas?

```
this.sourceStream$.takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).someFunc((data) => {
  return data['some tranformation']
}).subscribe(data => {
```

If there any way to do this without a variable to track if the first value has been received?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not consider take(1) operator?

Comment: @siva636 because I still want to subscribe to future emissions, I just don't want to "map" them

Comment: are you just not looking for `startsWith` here? Maybe not, but it might be a better option if you want to start emitting directly with a known value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `map` operator has a second argument `index` that is automatically incremented:

```
this.sourceStream$.map((value, index) =>
  index === 0 ? whatever(value) : value
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a combination of `take` `skip` and `merge`.

Something along these lines should do the trick, even if a bit verbose

```
const obs = Observable.interval(1000).take(4);

const obs1 = obs.take(1).map(val => 'I am the fist '+ val);
const obs2 = obs.skip(1);

merge(obs1, obs2).subscribe(console.log)
```